# Change NSTableView header color & font size & row height

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I spent hours to find how to make this, all subjects discuss iOS not Mac, I want to control the header for table by changing height, background color, font etc. as in another table Cell's ... any body help me please!

I made the code below to change header for column 0, but the result is: header with text "name" but without colour and row height!

```
NSTableHeaderCell *cell = [[NSTableHeaderCell alloc]initTextCell:@"name"];

[cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];

[cell drawWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 20, 30) inView:[[tableView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:0]];

[[[tableView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:0] setHeaderCell:cell];
```

also I tried to use this

```
NSTableHeaderView *headerView = [[NSTableHeaderView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 120, 60)];
[tableView setHeaderView:headerView];
```

But I got the same original header withe my custom view in back (both)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking at NSTableColumn's method [setHeaderCell:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstablecolumn_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableColumn/setHeaderCell%3a)

There you can customise the cell used to display the table headers.

Comment: I made an example above, still need help

Comment: setting the header cell background won't affect the whole header view. that's the problem. setting the header cell only looks terrible.